# Android Studio. Один проектом ссылается на другой

Tags: java, android-studio

У меня есть два проекта, используемые в одном эмуляторе. Когда я пытаюсь перейти при нажатии на кнопку с файла MainActivity из проекта 1 в файл MainActivity2 в проекте 1, у меня ничего не получается. Однако, если я попытаюсь перейти в файл TestActivity в проекте 2, он спокойно переходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```
package com.example.itfest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton img_1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    img_1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img_but_1);
    img_1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(".TestActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

}
```

И верхушечка XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/back_">
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
```